# Angular 6: DebounceTime, only take the last value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a input to search objects in my database and show in a table, well, the input is reactive, and search when I stop writing there for 1,5 secs. For that I have this code

```
const input = document.getElementById('buscaUsuario');

    fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map((k: KeyboardEvent) => k.target['value']),
        debounceTime(1500),
      ).subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
        if (val !== '') {
          console.log('search the user');
          this._usuarioService.buscarUsuarios(val)
            .subscribe( (usuarios: Usuario[]) => {
              this.usuarios = usuarios;
              this.cargando = false;
            });
        }
      });
```

Well the problem is that I put the `console.log` to see if only execute the function one time, because before use `debounceTime`, the app make a new request to the backend in each keyup. I think this solve my request, but when I put the `console.log` I could see that the function is executed the same numbers of characters I put in the input.

for example if I write "user" in the input i have this in the console

> usuarios.component.ts:84 user
>
> usuarios.component.ts:86 search the user
>
> usuarios.component.ts:84 user
>
> usuarios.component.ts:86 search the user
>
> usuarios.component.ts:84 user
>
> usuarios.component.ts:86 search the user

What can I do to only execute `this._usuarioService.buscarUsuarios` one time, after the user stop writing in the input for 1500ms ?

**SOLUTION:**

The problem is that, in the input in the HTML i put (keyup)="buscarUsuario()", then in each keyup i execute the function.

The solution, remove the keyup and put my function in the ngOnInit.

This is the new code (Thanks to Adrian Brand and Krishna Rathore to helping me find the solution)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cargarUsuarios();

    this.cargando = true;

    // Seleccionamos el input en el documento
    const input = document.getElementById('buscaUsuario');

    // En el evento indicado para el elemento seleccionado ejecutamos el pipe y luego el subscribe
    fromEvent(input, 'input')
      .pipe(
        // Tomamos las letras ingresadas
        map((k: KeyboardEvent) => k.target['value']),
        // Seleccionamos un tiempo en milisegundos antes de continuar la ejecución luego de que se presionó la última letra
        debounceTime(1500),
        // Ahora si ejecutamos la busqueda del usuario con el total de letras en el input
        // luego de que se dejara de escribir por 1,5 segundos
      ).subscribe(val => {
        if (val !== '') {
          this._usuarioService.buscarUsuarios(val)
            .subscribe( (usuarios: Usuario[]) => {
              this.usuarios = usuarios;
              this.cargando = false;
            });
        } else {
          this.cargarUsuarios();
          return;
        }
      });

  }
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/

Comment: You're gonna want to use switchMap to make your request to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `nativeElement` for bind `keyup` event.

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-debouncetime-only-take-the-last-value51960446?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

> component.html

```
<input type="text"  #buscaUsuario>
```

> component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild('buscaUsuario') buscaUsuario: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(this.buscaUsuario.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
      map((k: KeyboardEvent) => k.target.value),
      debounceTime(1500),
    ).subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
      if (val !== '') {
        console.log('search the user');
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks to you i found the solution, i go to put in the first post now Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are doing wrong but it only fires for the last key that I press after 1.5 seconds.

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { map, debounceTime } = rxjs.operators;

const input = document.getElementById('input');

fromEvent(input, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map(k => k.target.value),
        debounceTime(1500),
      ).subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks to you and the next answer i found the problem, in my input i call in every keyup the function buscarUsuario because i have (keyup)="buscarUsuario( input.value )", but if i put the FormEvent in the ngOnInit i capture the keyup in the formEvent and works perfect!